# Visual Studio 2022 / CMake - Can't enable Debug Info for Release mode

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

This is my `CMakeUserPresets.json`:

```
  {
    "version": 3,
    "configurePresets": [
      {
        "name": "Debug",
        "inherits": "Qt-Default",
        "binaryDir": "${sourceDir}/out/build",
        "toolchainFile": "V:/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake",
        "cacheVariables": {
          "CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE": "Debug",
          "CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS": "-DQT_QML_DEBUG"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "Release",
        "inherits": "Qt-Default",
        "binaryDir": "${sourceDir}/out/build",
        "toolchainFile": "V:/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake",
        "cacheVariables": {
          "CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE": "Release",
          "CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS": "/Zi"
        }
      },
      {
        "hidden": true,
        "name": "Qt-Default",
        "inherits": "6.5.2",
        "vendor": {
          "qt-project.org/Default": {
            "checksum": "vc6/MpVy4UeFvNIolNCZsZaSktQ="
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "hidden": true,
        "name": "6.5.2",
        "inherits": "Qt",
        "environment": {
          "QTDIR": "C:/QT/6.5.2/MSVC2019_64"
        },
        "architecture": {
          "strategy": "external",
          "value": "x64"
        },
        "generator": "Ninja",
        "vendor": {
          "qt-project.org/Version": {
            "checksum": "71XQm7RlUjKDu6zD0hF/SOKXrso="
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "vendor": {
      "qt-project.org/Presets": {
        "checksum": "G1tec/1E8Gz7qPZZvjFUlaUAxIE="
      }
    }
  }
```

I have a program I have build using Qt6.5.2 and I want to make sure that I have enable Debug Info for my Release version of the app. I have tried by adding `"CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS": "/Zi"` to the Release section, however it still looks like there is no Debug info for my Release version.

How can I enable it, what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: "however it still looks like there is no Debug info" - How exactly have you deduce absence of debug information? Have you inspected command lines which call the compiler and check whether these command lines actually contains `/Zi` option?

Comment: I see this: https://pastebin.com/L9KhfwTB

Comment: @Tsyvarev also when I have this in Release it does not build .pdb files.

Comment: So, `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` has been passed to the **project**. But whether the project **respects** the passed value or it **redefines** the variable? We don't know that. That is why it is useful to check the command line which invokes the **compiler**. In case of ninja you could run `ninja -v`.

Comment: show us what the output of the configuration command is when you run it fresh (see `--fresh`) want to see if Ninja is actually being used as the generator. I also want to see what command you are using to invoke configuration. I also want to see the compilation options in the compileCommands.json file. Please use https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS.html and show us what you see.